# Unable to generate temporary class for web service

Tags: c#

I have an application with a proxy class for my webservice - This works fine in all 32-bit machines. However the same app throws an exception in windows server 2008 64-bit machine. It looks like the temporary class could not be generated for the web service. The error in the event viewer is "error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file '' -- 'Bad Key. '
Here's the call stack...
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
   at Fusion.ServiceCatalogProxy..ctor()

I am not able to get any info about this bad key error....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your referenced assemblies is [corrupted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd1y3633.aspx).

Comment: The same build works in other machines - Server 2003 32-bit for example. Is there any way to know the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

If your build configuration type is "AnyCPU" then sometimes accessing com objects those are only available for 32 bit interface sometime creates problem, try re building your app/project with x86 and then on 64 bit machine any 32 bit program will function exactly same.

By looking at the error, I can see that on 64 bit machine the temp folder may be placed in different location and your 32 bit program can not find it.